# URL Routing is not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-routing

I am using the simple code to do URL Re-writing in a web based application.

Here is my global files code:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Login", "Admin/LoginPage", "~/Admin/login.aspx");

}
```

I have added the following lines in Web.config file also:

```
 <httpModules>
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"></add>
</httpModules>
```

I Dont know why this is not working for me. Please help me..

Comment: @codebrain i am using 4.0

Comment: check this link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: @SirwanAfifi i am not working in MVC

Comment: I have create a new Project with 4.0 framework and then paste all the content to that it works, it might be the problem in conversion. Actually this project was in lower version(2.0 framework) because of that i have convert it to latest version 4.0. 


By the way thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the URL Rewrite Extension installed in IIS?

Comment: Why would you need that? The UrlRouting module doesn't require you to have this extension installed.

Comment: In my installation, I don't have the module in my web.config file, but I needed to install the url routing. At least that is what I remember.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you added the module to the wrong place (`<system.web>/<httpModules>`).

If you are hosting your application in IIS in Integrated Pipeline mode you should add the module to the `<system.webServer>/<modules>` node:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"></add>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```